# Microsoft Graph API support for applicationRefs information

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, azureadgraph-deprecation

The Azure port still uses the Azure AD Graph API in some places. One thing it uses this for is to list API permissions. For this, the portal uses the REST API target `GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applicationRefs/c5393580-f805-4401-95e8-94b7a6ef2fc2?api-version=2.0` (example shown for Office 365 Management API). I've searched and cannot seem to find a way to list similar permission sets using the Microsoft Graph API. Is there a way to access this using the Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: Could you share the link to the example?

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by a link to the example. The URL example I provided in the original question. Another example for Microsoft Graph permissions using curl: `curl 'https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applicationRefs/00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000?api-version=2.0' -H 'Authorization: Bearer <token value>`

Comment: I mean the official document about applicationRefs. I couldn't find the API in Azure AD Graph API.

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution I provided below helps your problem ?

Comment: Any update ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, was going to upvote one of the previous answers, but my profile is too new. :( You can do this by reading the MS Graph service principal in your tenant as described above. This [PowerShell code](https://github.com/adamedx/autographps-sdk/blob/main/src/common/ScopeHelper.ps1) gives an example (it's used in a command called `Find-GraphPermission` in the `autographps` and `autographps-sdk` modules.

Basic approach is:

1. Get app-only permissions from the `appRoles` property of the `servicePrincipal`
2. Get delegated permissions from the `publishedPermissionScopes` property
3. Each element of `appRoles` has an id that can be read or written from a given `appRoleAssigment` object on an app's `servicePrincipal` in your tenant. Note that each `appRole` element has a `value` property that is the common friendly name of the app-only permission (e.g. `BitlockerKey.ReadBasic.All`
4. A similar `id` and `value` pair exists for each element of `publishedPermissionScopes` which gives you the delegated permissions. You can use those ids with `oauth2PermissionGrant` objects under the segment `/oauth2PermissionGrants` to enumerate consent grants for a given `servicePrincipal` (and thus `app`) in your tenant or grant or remove consent

Note that the ids for both `appRoles` and `publishedPermissionScopes` are the same in all tenants, so you can actually perform this same mapping of friendly names to ids for any tenant, and use a static snapshot. This can be useful as your application may not be able to read the Microsoft Graph `servicePrincipal` object. If you store a static version, you'll have the mapping regardless and you'll only miss any new permissions that get added to Microsoft Graph for new APIs.

This file contains a snapshot of the MS Graph `servicePrincipal` as a fairly readable JSON-like PowerShell hash table: https://github.com/adamedx/autographps-sdk/blob/main/src/common/DefaultScopeData.ps1

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, you can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) microsoft graph api: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<object id of the application>`

It will response the result like below screenshot(please pay attention to the field `requiredResourceAccess`):
[image]

The content under `requiredResourceAccess` is the API permissions of this application. The type `scope` means the permission is **Delegated** type and the type `role` means the permission is **Application** type.

Then please refer to steps below to know which permission does the `id` under `resourceAccess` field refer to.

1. Copy the `resourceAppId`, in my screenshot is `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`. And request the graph api: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals?$filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'`
2. Copy one of the `id` under `resourceAccess` field in the response of first graph api. For example copy the first id `a154bxxxxxxxxxxx59` in my first screenshot. And then search this id in the response of second graph api, we can find this id refer to `User.Read.All` permission.
   [image]

Comment: This does not work for third-party installed applications. First, `v1.0/applications/` cannot be used to pull installed application info from another tenant. Second, when I take the appId / service principal ID from the external application and use that to search under `v1.0/serviceprincipals`, the resulting `appRoles` and `oauth2PermissionScopes` arrays are empty. What you describe works fine for locally installed / developed applications where the service principal identity is in the tenant. But it doesn't work for installed external applications.

Comment: Note that `beta/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignments` almost gets us there, but it doesn't provide the readable name for a permission/scope.